# Leaflet (React-Leaflet) custom renderer

Tags: leaflet, react

I am reposting a question that i asked in [stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61600099/custom-shape-of-circlemarker-or-better-approach) about leaflet and custom renderers.

Basically what i want to achieve is create a custom renderer that alters the shape of CircleMarker or extend the Path constructor to create custom shaped (vector) Markers.

What i've done so far is this:

```
import {
  CircleMarker as LeafletCircleMarker,
  Canvas as LeafletCanvas,
} from "leaflet";
import { withLeaflet, Path } from "react-leaflet";

const myRenderer = (layer) => LeafletCanvas({ padding: 0.5 });

class CustomMarker extends Path {
  createLeafletElement(props) {
    const enhancedProps = {
      ...props,
      renderer: myRenderer
    };

    const el = new LeafletCircleMarker(
      props.center,
      this.getOptions(enhancedProps)
    );
    this.contextValue = { ...props.leaflet, popupContainer: el };
    debugger;
    return el;
  }

  updateLeafletElement(fromProps, toProps) {
    if (toProps.center !== fromProps.center) {
      this.leafletElement.setLatLng(toProps.center);
    }

    if (toProps.radius !== fromProps.radius) {
      this.leafletElement.setRadius(toProps.radius);
    }
  }
}

export default withLeaflet(CustomMarker);
```

I am just setting the Canvas constructor as a renderer like the examples in the Leaflet docs but i am getting an `Error: The provided object is not a Layer` in `layer/Layer.js:159` `addLayer` function.

Can someone please instruct me in how to implement a renderer?

Comment: Could you add a link to your SO question to keep things connected?

Comment: i will (add the link)...also i figure it out so i will add an answer.
also if anyone has a better approach i would love to hear (read) it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ok so after reading [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51850249/leaflet-js-too-slow-with-custom-svg-markers-and-a-lot-of-points) SO answer I managed to implement something similar for `react-leaflet`. Currently it just uses the code of leaflet's `Canvas` `_updateCircle` method, but it's a start for different shapes.

```
import {
  CircleMarker as LeafletCircleMarker,
  Canvas as LeafletCanvas,
} from "leaflet";
import { withLeaflet, Path } from "react-leaflet";

LeafletCanvas.include({
  _updateCustomMarker: function (layer) {
    if (!this._drawing || layer._empty()) {
      return;
    }

    var p = layer._point,
      ctx = this._ctx,
      r = Math.max(Math.round(layer._radius), 1),
      s = (Math.max(Math.round(layer._radiusY), 1) || r) / r;

    if (s !== 1) {
      ctx.save();
      ctx.scale(1, s);
    }

    ctx.beginPath();
    ctx.arc(p.x, p.y / s, r, 0, Math.PI * 2, false);

    if (s !== 1) {
      ctx.restore();
    }

    this._fillStroke(ctx, layer);
  },
});

class CustomMarker extends Path {
  createLeafletElement(props) {
    const MyMarker = LeafletCircleMarker.extend({
      _updatePath: function () {
        this._renderer._updateCustomMarker(this);
      },
    });

    const el = new MyMarker(props.center, this.getOptions(props));
    this.contextValue = { ...props.leaflet, popupContainer: el };

    return el;
  }

  updateLeafletElement(fromProps, toProps) {
    if (toProps.center !== fromProps.center) {
      this.leafletElement.setLatLng(toProps.center);
    }

    if (toProps.radius !== fromProps.radius) {
      this.leafletElement.setRadius(toProps.radius);
    }
  }
}

export default withLeaflet(CustomMarker);
```

I hope my answer can help someone else.